# Unable to get files pushed with compiled code to Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have 2 questions:

1. I need some json data from a json file which I am copying while
   building the project. Then I published the code from visual studio
   2015 but when the code runs on Azure, it can't access the file in
   the folder from where dll is being executed. How can I get data from
   that file.
2. When I pushed the Azure function from visual studio to Azure,
   appsettings.json values are not being published to Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refrain from asking 2 questions in one.

The answers:

1. You can get the path to current directory from Execution Context, see [Retrieving information about the currently running function](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function).
2. `App.setting` file is not used in actual deployment of FunctionApp, you should define your settings in environment variables, see [How to manage a function app in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#a-namesettingsaapplication-settings).

Comment: I have written Azure functions using c#, and here, I can't see the option for functiondirectory. Also, I think, this can be done using Azure Functions External File Bindings as it supports accessing the file from file system but I could not figure out how to use it as I could not find any example of it. There are other options of Dropbox or Google Drive for getting the file from these bindings but I am preferring local File System of Azure.